# keccak256 doesn't return buffer

Tags: hash, buffer, blockchain, ethereum

I have the following:

```js
static combinedHash(first: Buffer, second: Buffer): Buffer {
    if (!first) {
      return second
    }
    if (!second) {
      return first
    }
    return keccak256(MerkleTree.sortAndConcat(first, second))
  }
```

`keccak256` is imported from `ethereumjs-utils`

It seems like that `keccak256` returns `Buffer`.

What I am trying to do is I want to change `keccak256` from `ethereumjs-utils` to `ethers/lib/utils`, but new `keccak256` doesn't return buffer. I tried lots of things, but the results are different. any ideas ? The final result should be that `combinedHash` function returns the same thing in the end so it should return `Buffer`.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

`ethers/lib/utils` function `keccak256()` returns `0x` prefixed hex string representation of the hash.

So you need to create a buffer from this hex without the `0x` prefix.

```
const keccakString = keccak256(MerkleTree.sortAndConcat(first, second))
return Buffer.from(keccakString.slice('0x'.length), 'hex')
```